# get result from array of objects retrieved from db and return to ng-template

Tags: html, css, angular, mongodb

I have a complex array of objects retrieved from db

**[Link to the Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oapam2)**

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "userId": "-jgtgjS",
        "firstName": "def",
        "lastName": "yellow",
        "email": "def@gm.com",
        "otp": 0,
        "otpExpiry": "",
        "mobileNumber": 9852145987,
        "createdOn": "2019-09-15T11:50:29Z",
        "gender": "female",
        "profilePic": "",
        "friendList": {
            "_id": "5d7e25852fffaa2858930878",
            "userId": "-jgtgjS",
            "friendCount": 0,
            "userObject": "5d7e25852fffaa2858930877",
            "allFriends": [
                {
                    "friendId": "GsbItTr",
                    "requestSent": true,
                    "requestReceived": false,
                    "friendSince": 1568549711731,
                    "_id": "5d7e2b2f25207f161c718a64",
                    "friendObject": "5d7e285aa6132b179cfa917c"
                },
                {
                    "friendId": "ch4PXXn",
                    "requestSent": false,
                    "requestReceived": true,
                    "friendSince": "",
                    "_id": "5d7f16124c7b3f16ec308c1d",
                    "friendObject": "5d7dce8d2a719a1d188ed641"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 2
        }
    }]
```

**[Link to the Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oapam2)**

I am using `*ngFor` to display the friends in my template, but I also need to show whether he is friend or not, how can I pass the instance of `*ngFor` before display to .ts and then compute the boolean and then return back to the template so that the user displayed is friend or not.

Added a pic. Now the button shows add friend in each using `ngFor`. but depending on the status of each user the button would change to accept if a request is received or it will show friends if the request is already accepted and `friendSince` has some value

I am able to get the status like this.

```js
ar[0].friendList.allFriends.forEach(element=>{
    if (element.friendId=='ch4PXXn'){
        sent=element.requestSent;
        received=element.requestReceived;
    }
});
```

[image]

if u refer to the image added.. u can see there are many users listed in the view using *ngfor. 'def yellow' is one of them. Now inside of users object there is another array of objects which stores all the friend request transactions happening. This view is being seen by userId 'ch4PXXn'. So I need to find the object inside allFriends with a friendId containing ch4PXXn and then based on other parameters like sent, received, since. I want to show a button which will give user ch4PXXn options to accept or show request sent.

[Link to the Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oapam2)

Comment: I assume if `friendSince` is blank, then not friend else friend.. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.. with the help of these flags I want to show accept request | friends ✓

Comment: And what is the output you are expecting, can you share the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let friend of arr">
    <h3>{{friend.firstName}} {{friend.lastName}}</h3>
    <h4>{{friend.gender}} </h4>
    <h5>{{friend.email}} </h5>
    <h5>{{friend.mobileNumber}} </h5>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Friend Id </th>
            <th>Is Friend </th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of friend.friendList.allFriends">
            <td>{{item.friendId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.friendSince == '' ? 'Not Friend' : 'Friend'}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ft5ks9)**

Comment: Hi Adrita, maybe I didn't define the problem correctly.. if u refer to the image added.. u can see there are many users listed in the view using *ngfor. 'def yellow' is one of them. Now inside of users object there is another array of objects which stores all the friend request transactions happening. This view is being seen by userId 'ch4PXXn'. So I need to find the object inside allFriends with a friendId containing ch4PXXn and then based on other parameters like sent, received, since. I want to show a button which will give user ch4PXXn options to accept or show request sent.

Comment: How can I refer to those Boolean values.. while ngfor is rendering each user. (Note: here def yellow is one of the many users) then maybe pass it to ts file and compute for every user that he is friend or not.. and then return it back to the template so a dynamic button can be shown

Comment: Ok.. CAn you share your html, otherwise I have to recreate it in the link shared

Comment: The one you shared is my link, I think you forgot to fork it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `*ngFor`, where you iterate the `allFriends` array, and based on your conditions show different content:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of friend.friendList.allFriends; let last = last">
  <!-- First check that friend matches the current user -->
  <div *ngIf="a.friendId === loggedInUser">
    <!-- are you already friends? -->
    <p *ngIf="a.friendSince">You are friends!</p>
    <!-- You have received a request, but not yet accepted -->
    <button *ngIf="a.requestReceived && !a.friendSince> Accept Friend request</button>
    <!-- You have sent request, but user hasn't accepted -->
    <button disabled *ngIf="a.requestSent && !a.friendSince">Friend Request Sent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- All above conditions are false, and it is last item in array -->
  <button *ngIf="a.friendId !== loggedInUser && last">Add Friend</button>
</ng-container>
```

**[Here's a STACKBLIZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkqx6p?file=src/app/app.component.html)**